# on demand tree view in mvc collapse when click on other nodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need a tree view in my mvc web application to show the list items, 
when clicking on a node in tree view, the child nodes should come(on demand), the other nodes should collapse, and also when coming to the view with an id, it should expand the section nodes.

Is there any way to do this ?

I have used 'http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-populate-treeview-nodes-dynamic-ondemand-mvc4.html'

But when clicking on one node, the other nodes not collapse,
any control to do this in mvc ?

Comment: There are plenty of 3rd party libraries for this - e.g. [Kendo Treeview](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/index) and more [here](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/TreeView)

Comment: I need a tree view which loads its contents on demand, mean only when clicking on a node, it should load the content from db, and also when click on a node, all other nodes should collapse like an accordion.

Comment: Look at the links I gave you. The Kendo one has an example of 'Binding to remote data' (which loads the data from a controller when you click on it). If they are not suitable, write your own jquery plugin

Comment: there's also this: http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/TreeGrid#Lazy-loading-Nodes-Tree-Grid (it's not free, commercial), header and footer can be hidden so it looks like a treeview, the menu on the left is like that